# Nginx adding domain

Tags: nginx

Setting up a site on digitalocean it's working on a default ip that comes with the setup. I've added a domain to the instance and edited the nginx conf file to add a subdomain for testing purposes. I've restarted nginx but the changes aren't taking effect. Here's the conf settings.

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _ beta.kazi-connect.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

Comment: You pointing the domain to that VPS specific IP? If so, it could be the TTL taking it's time to mitigate (usually up to ~48 hours). It could also be `server_name _ beta.kazi-connect.com`, why the `_`?

Comment: `_` was there by default I assume it's cover all which I'd assume means it covers all, it's okay since the server is only intended to host one site. I've added the server names `ns1.digitalocean.com` but not the A record. when I visit the domain I get a 502 error by nginx which to me means it's pointing to the server correctly.

Comment: Next step is to check your error logs - `ls -l /var/log/nginx/error.log`, is there anything in there?

Comment: response by support "It seems that Nginx is not routing a server block with the server_name of beta.kazi-connect.com to the same location as is being served at http://138.197.43.213. You may want to review the configuration and make sure that you restart Nginx after any changes."

Comment: 2017/01/24 07:12:30 [error] 25117#25117: *95 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 150.70.173.41, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com"